# Define multiprecision pi in boost:multiprecision

Tags: c++, boost

I need pi (3.1415...) in arbitrary (but fixed) precision in `boost::multiprecision`.

The constants in `boost::math::constants` are only defined up to a fixed number of digits, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491868/931303), so I need to compute it by myself.

Because I'm using this number often and with a very large number of digits, I would like to compute it in runtime only once. what would be a simple yet fast way to have it?

I thought using

```
typedef number<cpp_dec_float<PRECISION> > mpfloat;  // PRECISION is compile time.

const int PI = atan(mpfloat(1))*4;
```

but I'm not sure this is a common idiom for it.

Comment: So you're saying you want to compute pi to an arbitrary number of digits at runtime when your program starts?

Comment: You do realize that that's the kind of thing you see in the news, right? Calculating pi is a resource-intensive process.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. With arbitrary I didn't mean infinitely large, just with a fixed but large precision. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

In c++14 you can use a template variable (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template).

Note that you can already have what you want by including

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/detail/default_ops.hpp>
```

That header ends up including `constants.hpp` which defines `template <class T> const T& get_constant_pi()`.

This is the c++03 idiom for template variables already (as it stores a function-local static result value).

`calc_pi` has the first 1100 digits hardcoded, and the rest is calculated via optimized formulae if required.

#### Demo with 50 and 5000 digits:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru (c++14)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b3382deddceb1ba)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/detail/default_ops.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    namespace bmp = boost::multiprecision;

    template <int N> bmp::number<bmp::cpp_dec_float<N> > const my_const_pi 
        = bmp::default_ops::get_constant_pi<bmp::cpp_dec_float<N> >();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(50)   << my_const_pi<50>   << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5000) << my_const_pi<5000> << "\n";
}
```

Prints

> 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
>   3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989380952572010654858632788659361533818279682303019520353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295331168617278558890750983817546374649393192550604009277016711390098488240128583616035637076601047101819429555961989467678374494482553797747268471040475346462080466842590694912933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533824300355876402474964732639141992726042699227967823547816360093417216412199245863150302861829745557067498385054945885869269956909272107975093029553211653449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746728909777727938000816470600161452491921732172147723501414419735685481613611573525521334757418494684385233239073941433345477624168625189835694855620992192221842725502542568876717904946016534668049886272327917860857843838279679766814541009538837863609506800642251252051173929848960841284886269456042419652850222106611863067442786220391949450471237137869609563643719172874677646575739624138908658326459958133904780275900994657640789512694683983525957098258226205224894077267194782684826014769909026401363944374553050682034962524517493996514314298091906592509372216964615157098583874105978859597729754989301617539284681382686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958486538367362226260991246080512438843904512441365497627807977156914359977001296160894416948685558484063534220722258284886481584560285060168427394522674676788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743241125150760694794510965960940252288797108931456691368672287489405601015033086179286809208747609178249385890097149096759852613655497818931297848216829989487226588048575640142704775551323796414515237462343645428584447952658678210511413547357395231134271661021359695362314429524849371871101457654035902799344037420073105785390621983874478084784896833214457138687519435064302184531910484810053706146806749192781911979399520614196634287544406437451237181921799983910159195618146751426912397489409071864942319615679452080951465502252316038819301420937621378559566389377870830390697920773467221825625996615014215030680384477345492026054146659252014974428507325186660021324340881907104863317346496514539057962685610055081066587969981635747363840525714591028970641401109712062804390397595156771577004203378699360072305587631763594218731251471205329281918261861258673215791984148488291644706095752706957220917567116722910981690915280173506712748583222871835209353965725121083579151369882091444210067510334671103141267111369908658516398315019701651511685171437657618351556508849099898599823873455283316355076479185358932261854896321329330898570642046752590709154814165498594616371802709819943099244889575712828905923233260972997120844335732654893823911932597463667305836041428138830320382490375898524374417029132765618093773444030707469211201913020330380197621101100449293215160842444859637669838952286847831235526582131449576857262433441893039686426243410773226978028073189154411010446823252716201052652272111660396665573092547110557853763466820653109896526918620564769312570586356620185581007293606598764861179104533488503461136576867532494416680396265797877185560845529654126654085306143444318586769751456614068007002378776591344017127494704205622305389945613140711270004078547332699390814546646458807972708266830634328587856983052358089330657574067954571637752542021149557615814002501262285941302164715509792592309907965473761255176567513575178296664547791745011299614890304639947132962107340437518957359614589019389713111790429782856475032031986915140287080859904801094121472213179476477726224142548545403321571853061422881375850430633217518297986622371721591607716692547487389866549494501146540628433663937900397692656721463853067360965712091807638327166416274888800786925602902284721040317211860820419000422966171196377921337575114959501566049631862947265473642523081770367515906735023507283540567040386743513622224771589150495309844489333096340878076932599397805419341447377441842631298608099888687413260472

Comment: what about when the precision is not known 'til runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just putting the [value of pi](http://www.piday.org/million/) into your source code as a constant with however many digits you need.

Answer (score 0):

Define it as a static within a struct.

Comment: In C++, it is not necessary, and someone unidiomatic, to put global variables inside a struct. Rather you can just put them at file scope (or function scope of course).

Comment: declaring global variables is not recommended. namespace or function scope can be used. I didn't say anything about using global variable here

Comment: There is absolutely no recommendation difference between a global variable inside a struct and a global variable outside a struct. They are both evil for the purposes of "avoid globals".